# How to order custom fields in the user profile (admin area)

Tags: user-meta, profiles

I’ve added a custom section to the user profile in my own theme. The section is called „Extra Profilinformationen“ for now and includes a field for twitter. It’s added to the bottom. Is there any way to place it before the profile image? How can I change the order of it?

[image]

```php
function my_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
  <h3>Extra Profilinformationen</h3>
  <table class="form-table">
    <tr>
      <th><label for="twitter">Twitter</label></th>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="twitter" id="twitter" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'twitter', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
        <p class="description">Füge ein Twitterprofil hinzu.</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<?php }
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );

function my_save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
  if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) {
    return false;
  }
  update_usermeta( $user_id, 'twitter', $_POST['twitter'] );
}
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );
```

Comment: You should probably include the code used to create the extra profile fields.

Comment: You probably want to add Twitter as a user_contactmethod, e.g. [Yoast's code](https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/blob/12.7.1/admin/class-admin.php#L261). These appear at the bottom of 'Contact Info', above 'About Yourself'.

Comment: @RiddleMeThis I’ve added the code I used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no action hooks on `user-edit.php` that would allow you to place html before the profile image. One option is to use javascript/jquery to move the html around the profile page.

But as @RiddleMeThis mentioned on the comments, you can use `user_contactmethods` filter to add custom contact methods such as Twitter to the profile page.

```
add_filter('user_contactmethods', 'my_user_contactmethods');

function my_user_contactmethods($contactmethods){

  $contactmethods['twitter'] = __('Twitter Username', 'textdomain');

  return $contactmethods;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I’ve added the user_contactmethods filter to my theme.